# Can't get jQuery autcomplete to work. (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to follow the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826852/asp-net-mvc-please-help-with-search-in-data-entry-form-thanks) by [tvanfosson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12950/tvanfosson).
I just can't get it to work.  I think the problem is with my JavaScript (?).
I say that because if I navigate in my browser to http://localhost:49790/Books/GetBooks/?q= then the browser downloads a file with the information that I'd expect in the format I'd expect:

```
[{"BookName":"Book 1","AuthorName":"Author 1","BookID":2},{"BookName":"Book 2","AuthorName":"Author 2","BookID":3}]
```

But back on the view, when I start typing in the SearchBox, nothing happens.  No autocomplete.

Here is my view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    jQuerySearch
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#SearchBox').autocomplete('/Books/GetBooks', {
            dataType: 'json',
            max: 25,
            minChars: 1,
            cacheLength: 1,
            mustMatch: true,
            formatItem: function(data, i, max, value) {
                return value;
            },
            parse: function(data) {
                var array = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var datum = data[i];
                    var display = datum.AuthorName + ' - ' + datum.BookName;
                    array[array.length] = { data: datum, value: display, result: display };
                }
            }
        });

        $('#SearchBox').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            if (data) {
                $('#BookID').val(data.BookID);
            }
        });

        $('form').submit(function() {
            if (!$('#BookID').val()) {
                alert('You must select a book before clicking submit!');
                return false;
            }
        });




    });
        </script>
    <h2>jQuerySearch</h2>

    <%using (Html.BeginForm()){%>

        <%=Html.TextBox("SearchBox") %>
        <input type='hidden' id='BookID' name='BookID' />

    <%}; %>


</asp:Content>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
 public ActionResult GetBooks(string q)
{
var query = db.Books.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(q))
                            .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
                            .Select(e => new
                            {
                                BookName = e.Name,
                                AuthorName = e.Author.Name,
                                BookID = e.BookID
                            });

      return Json(query.ToList());
  }
```

I'm pretty new to all this.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any JS errors.  Here is another similar post that deals with the parse aspect:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529652/jquery-autocomplete-results-format

Comment: OK, I got it.  There was no JS error because autocomplete was never executing.  I had to change $('#SearchBox') to $('input#SearchBox').
I also had to add  "return array;" as dcneiner pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your array at the end of the `parse` function:

```
parse: function(data) {
    var array = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var datum = data[i];
        var display = datum.AuthorName + ' - ' + datum.BookName;
        array[array.length] = { data: datum, value: display, result: display };
    }
    return array; // Add this line
}
```

Comment: That was one of the problems.  The other problem is I had to reference my textfield as $('input#SearchBox').autocomplete instead of $('SearchBox').autocomplete.

Thanks.

Comment: If that caused a problem, it probably means you have more than one html element on your page with that id. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The parser method was giving us a headache in a recent project especially with IE 6 & 8.
So we opted to use it this way:
remenber to add the references:

jQuery Core

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery Autocomplete

```
<link href="../../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

try something like this:
Controller

```
public ActionResult Completer(string q)
        {
            if (q != "")
            {
                NWDataContext db = new NWDataContext();
                var suggest = from i in db.Customers
                                  .Where(e => e.ContactName.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower()))
                                   select (i.ContactName + "|" + i.CustomerID);
                return Content(String.Join("\n", suggest.ToArray()));
            }
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

This will return something like :

```
Ana Trujillo|ANATR
Antonio Moreno|ANTON
Ann Devon|EASTC
Aria Cruz|FAMIA
André Fonseca|GOURL
Annette Roulet|LAMAI
```

and in your View:

```
$('#Clientes').autocomplete(' <% =Url.Action("Completer","Home") %>', {
                width: 300,
                formatItem: formatItem,
                formatResult: formatResult
            });
```

and define formatItem and Format result like:

```
 function formatItem(row) {
                return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
            }
function formatResult(row) {
                return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
            }
```

Hope it helps.
You can take a look a this site [jquery-plugin-autocomplete-con-asp-net-mvc](http://www.diarioplus.com/2009/10/jquery-plugin-autocomplete-con-asp-net-mvc/), its in Spanish but there is a sample project that you can download at the end of the article.

Comment: should "formatItem: formatItemNoID," be "formatItem: formatItem,"?